# Access Thread args in Thread.run()

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a question based on an example from this [guide](https://superfastpython.com/thread-producer-consumer-pattern-in-python/#Shared_Buffer) (see code below):

In this example, when the thread is created a callback function and the `queue` are given as arguments. The callback functions uses `queue` as an argument. As far as I understood, this is possible because the thread arguments `args=(queue,)` are forwarded to the callback function elementwise.

My questions:

When writing my own Thread-class `class MyThread(Thread)` and overriding the `run()`-function, can I then also access the thread arguments like in the callback function?

```
class MyThread(Thread):
    def run(self, queue) -> None:
        pass

queue = queue.Queue()
myThread = MyThread(args=(queue,))
myThread.start
```

How do I use `kwargs`?

```
class MyThread(Thread):
    def run(self, ????) -> None:
        pass

queue = queue.Queue()
myThread = MyThread(kwargs={'queue',queue})
myThread.start
```

Does it make sense, to pass i.e. the `queue` argument directly to MyThread and hold the reference to this queue in a class variable?

```
class MyThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, group: None = None, target: Callable[..., object] | None = None, name: str | None = None, args: Iterable[Any] = ..., kwargs: Mapping[str, Any] | None = None, queue:Queue, *, daemon: bool | None = None) -> None:
        super().__init__(group, target, name, args, kwargs, daemon=daemon)
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self) -> None:
        # do something with self.queue
        pass

queue = queue.Queue()
myThread = MyThread(queue = queue)
myThread.start
```

Example code from the guide:

```
# SuperFastPython.com
# example of one producer and one consumer with threads
from time import sleep
from random import random
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue
 
# producer task
def producer(queue):
    print('Producer: Running')
    # generate items
    for i in range(10):
        # generate a value
        value = random()
        # block, to simulate effort
        sleep(value)
        # create a tuple
        item = (i, value)
        # add to the queue
        queue.put(item)
        # report progress
        print(f'>producer added {item}')
    # signal that there are no further items
    queue.put(None)
    print('Producer: Done')
 
# consumer task
def consumer(queue):
    print('Consumer: Running')
    # consume items
    while True:
        # get a unit of work
        item = queue.get()
        # check for stop
        if item is None:
            break
        # block, to simulate effort
        sleep(item[1])
        # report
        print(f'>consumer got {item}')
    # all done
    print('Consumer: Done')
 
# create the shared queue
queue = Queue()
# start the consumer
consumer = Thread(target=consumer, args=(queue,))
consumer.start()
# start the producer
producer = Thread(target=producer, args=(queue,))
producer.start()
# wait for all threads to finish
producer.join()
consumer.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to *assume* that you're asking about [`Threading.thread`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#thread-objects). If not, then don't read any further.

> How do I use kwargs?
>
> ```
> class MyThread(Thread):
>     def run(self, ????) -> None:
>         pass
> ```

You don't. When you `start` the new thread, its `run` method is only called with one arg, `self`. You can change how you declare it, but AFAIK, there's no easy way to change the code that will call it.

`Threading.thread` is easily useable for most purposes without any need to override anything. Just create the new thread with the desired `target` and `args`, and when you start the thread, the target function will be called with those args. Then the target function can do whatever it is that you need the new thread to do.

---

You said, in a comment (below),

> ...documentation indicates that I can create a thread with kwargs-argument...

Maybe you're looking to do something like this?

```py
import threading

def foo(first_arg, second_arg, **kwargs):
    print(f" first_arg: {first_arg}")
    print(f"second_arg: {second_arg}")
    print(f"    kwargs: {kwargs}")

def start_foo(*args, **kwargs):
    t = threading.Thread(target=foo, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    t.start()
    return t

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t = start_foo("one", "two", t="three", f="four")
    # probably do something else here
    t.join()
```

Comment: Following your suggestion to use the callback function instead of overriding the run-method, there is still the question of how to access the kwargs in the callback function? The documentation indicates that I can create a thread with `kwargs`-argument. From documentation: `class threading.Thread(group=None, target=None, name=None, args=(), kwargs={}, *, daemon=None)`

Comment: @paul_schaefer, see my expanded answer, above.